# Variable no se actualiza en Swift

Tags: swift, swiftui

estoy empezando a programar en swift con swiftUI, tratando de consumir una API REST, las funciones que he realizado traen los datos comprobados en la consola, he estado indagando en la red y no encuentro algo similar a mi código, al parecer que al usar URLSession.shared.dataTask es asíncrona, pero realmente no sé cómo solucionarlo ya que es un lenguaje completamente nuevo para mí, dejo mis códigos para que me puedan echar una mano con esto:

ClienteViewNodel:

```
import Foundation
import Combine

struct ClienteData: Codable {
    var codigo: Int?
    var nombre: String?
    var cuenta: String?
    var sucursalId: Int?
    
    init() {
        codigo = 0
        nombre = ""
        cuenta = ""
        sucursalId = 0
    }
}

struct LoginResponse: Codable {
    var code: Int?
    var status: String?
    var message: String?
    var data: ClienteData?
    
    init() {
        code = 0
        status = ""
        message = ""
        data = ClienteData()
    }
}

class ClienteViewModel: ObservableObject {
    
    func makeLogin (cuenta: String, clave: String, datos: @escaping(LoginResponse) -> ()) {
        guard let url = URL(string: "http://xxxxx.com/api/app/login") else {
            LoginViewModel().messageError = "Dirección API inválida!"
            return
        }
        
        //let body: [String: String] = ["cuenta": cuenta, "password": password]
        //let finalBody = try? JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: body)
        var request = URLRequest(url: url)
        
        request.httpMethod = "POST"
        request.setValue("application/x-www-form-urlencoded", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
        
        var params = URLComponents(url: url, resolvingAgainstBaseURL: false)!
        params.queryItems = [
            URLQueryItem(name: "cuenta", value: cuenta),
            URLQueryItem(name: "password", value: clave)
        ]
        
        if let query = params.url!.query {
            print("Parametros \(query)")
            request.httpBody = Data(query.utf8)
        }
        
        let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) {
            data, response, error in
            
            guard let cData = data, error == nil, let respuesta = response as? HTTPURLResponse else {
                LoginViewModel().messageError = "Ha ocurrido un error inesperado"
                return
            }
            
            if respuesta.statusCode == 200 {
                do {
                    let result = try JSONDecoder().decode(LoginResponse.self, from: cData)
                    datos(result)
                } catch let error {
                    LoginViewModel().messageError = error.localizedDescription
                }
            }
        }
        
        task.resume()
            
    }
}
```

LoginViewModel, aquí hago la llamada a la función makeLogin() e intento guardarla en la variable aDataSet pero no realizar ningún cambio:
import Foundation
import Combine

```
class LoginViewModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var cuenta = ""
    @Published var password = ""
    
    var messageError = ""
    
    var aDataSet = LoginResponse() {
        didSet {
            didChange.send(LoginViewModel())
        }
    }
    
    let didChange = PassthroughSubject<LoginViewModel, Never>()
}

extension LoginViewModel {
    
    func loginUser() -> Bool {
        
        ClienteViewModel().makeLogin(cuenta: self.cuenta, clave: self.password) { result in
            self.aDataSet = result
            print("Resultado makeLogin \(result)")
        }
            
        if aDataSet.code! == 404 {
            messageError = aDataSet.message!
            return false
        } else if aDataSet.code! == 500 {
            messageError = aDataSet.message!
            return false
        } else if aDataSet.code! == 200, aDataSet.status! == "fail" {
            messageError = aDataSet.message!
            return false
        } else if aDataSet.code! == 200, aDataSet.status! == "ok" {
            let token = UUID().uuidString
            UserDefaults.standard.set(token, forKey: "token")
            UserDefaults.standard.set(aDataSet.data!.cuenta!, forKey: "codigo")
            AppManager.Authenticated.send(true)
            
            return true
        } else {
            messageError = "Se ha producido un error inesperado!"
            return false
        }
    }
}
```

Espero me puedan esclarecer como resolver este problema.

Saludos.

Comment: No tengo claro cuál es el problema con el código si los datos que obtienes los muestras en consola.

Comment: en la función makeLogin trato de pasar los datos a la variable aDataset, e intento manejar esa información en la función LoginUser, a pesar de que le he pasado esa info aDataSet sigue vacía.

Answer (score 1):

Cuando se llama a una función dentro de la cual tienes un llamado a una función asíncrona tenemos que tomar en cuenta que todo el código se ejecuta de manera simultánea:

```
func loginUser() -> Bool {
    //Este código se ejecuta
    ClienteViewModel().makeLogin(cuenta: self.cuenta, clave: self.password) { result in
        self.aDataSet = result
        print("Resultado makeLogin \(result)")
    }
    //Este código también se ejecuta   
    if aDataSet.code! == 404 {
        messageError = aDataSet.message!
        return false
    } else if aDataSet.code! == 500 {
        messageError = aDataSet.message!
        return false
    } else if aDataSet.code! == 200, aDataSet.status! == "fail" {
        messageError = aDataSet.message!
        return false
    } else if aDataSet.code! == 200, aDataSet.status! == "ok" {
        let token = UUID().uuidString
        UserDefaults.standard.set(token, forKey: "token")
        UserDefaults.standard.set(aDataSet.data!.cuenta!, forKey: "codigo")
        AppManager.Authenticated.send(true)
        
        return true
    } else {
        messageError = "Se ha producido un error inesperado!"
        return false
    }
}
```

El resultado de llamar a `loginUser()` siempre va a ser `false` porque la variable `aDataSet` es vacía.

Puedes comprobar usando breakpoints o agregando `print()` para que en consola mires el valor de `aDataSet`.

**Función asíncrona**

Este llamado se ejecuta asíncronamente pero como ya devolviste un valor, ya no tienes acceso al nuevo valor asignado de `aDataSet`. Incluso en consola puedes ver el mensaje impreso.

```
ClienteViewModel().makeLogin(cuenta: self.cuenta, clave: self.password) { result in
    self.aDataSet = result
    print("Resultado makeLogin \(result)")
}
```

Una solución es remover `-> Bool` de la función:

```
func loginUser() { }
```

Y colocar las validaciones dentro del resultado de llamar a `makeLogin` porque aquí ya tienes un nuevo valor de `aDataSet`:

```
func loginUser() {
    
    ClienteViewModel().makeLogin(cuenta: self.cuenta, clave: self.password) { result in
        self.aDataSet = result
        print("Resultado makeLogin \(self.aDataSet)")
        
        if self.aDataSet.code! == 404 {
            self.messageError = self.aDataSet.message!
        } else if self.aDataSet.code! == 500 {
            self.messageError = self.aDataSet.message!
        } else if self.aDataSet.code! == 200, self.aDataSet.status! == "fail" {
            self.messageError = self.self.aDataSet.message!
        } else if self.aDataSet.code! == 200, self.self.aDataSet.status! == "ok" {
            let token = UUID().uuidString
            UserDefaults.standard.set(token, forKey: "token")
            UserDefaults.standard.set(self.aDataSet.data!.cuenta!, forKey: "codigo")
            AppManager.Authenticated.send(true)
            //Aquí como el login fue satisfactorio, sigues con el flujo de tu app.
        } else {
            self.messageError = "Se ha producido un error inesperado!"
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Es posible que al realizar la petición **http** de manera asincrónica no puedas obtener los datos de forma correcta así que podrías intentar modificar los parámetros de consulta de esta forma

```
let url = URL(string: "\(baseUrl)example")!
var request = URLRequest(url: url)
request.setValue("application/form-data", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
request.setValue("example_api", forHTTPHeaderField: "example_api_password")
request.httpMethod = "POST"
let postString = "username=\(userName.lowercased())&password=\(password.sha256())&grant_type=password"
request.httpBody = postString.data(using: .utf8)
```

Esto solo como un ejemplo básico ya que los datos no se reciben si alguna de estas opciones es definida de manera incorrecta, así que podrías modificar el método **`URLSession.shared.dataTask`** para que quede como algo así:

```
let loginCredentials = "user:password".data(using: .utf8)!.base64EncodedString()
let headers = [
    "Authorization": "Basic \(loginCredentials)",
    "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
]
var aDataSet:(message:String, data:Data?) = (message: "Fail", data: nil)
let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { data, response, error in 
    if (error != nil) {
        aDataSet.message = "Fail Error not null : \(error.debugDescription)"
    }
    else {
        aDataSet.message = "Success"
        aDataSet.data = data
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Viendo la respuesta de @Bicho me ha llevado a una pista para entender todo el asunto, indagando descubrí el ***DispatchQueue.main.async()***, haciendo pruebas y error la cosa así y ya funciona correctamente:

```
import Foundation
import Combine

class LoginViewModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var cuenta = ""
    @Published var password = ""
    @Published var loading = false
    @Published var hasError = false
    @Published var isLogged = false
    
    @Published var messageError = ""
    
    var aDataSet = LoginResponse(code: 0)
    
    func makeLogin () {
        guard let url = URL(string: "http://xxxxx.com/api/app/login") else {
            hasError = true
            messageError = "Dirección API inválida!"
            return
        }
        
        var request = URLRequest(url: url)
        
        request.httpMethod = "POST"
        request.setValue("application/x-www-form-urlencoded", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
        
        var params = URLComponents(url: url, resolvingAgainstBaseURL: false)!
        params.queryItems = [
            URLQueryItem(name: "cuenta", value: cuenta),
            URLQueryItem(name: "password", value: password)
        ]
        
        if let query = params.url!.query {
            request.httpBody = Data(query.utf8)
        }
        
        let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { [weak self]
            data, response, error in
            
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                
                if error != nil || (response as! HTTPURLResponse).statusCode != 200 {
                    self?.hasError = true
                    self?.messageError = error?.localizedDescription ?? "Ha ocurrido un problema inesperado."
                } else if let data = data {
                    do {
                        let result = try JSONDecoder().decode(LoginResponse.self, from: data)
                        
                        if result.code == 200, result.status == "fail" {
                            self?.hasError = true
                            self?.messageError = result.message!
                        } else if result.code == 404 {
                            self?.messageError = result.message!
                            self?.hasError = true
                        } else if result.code == 500 {
                            self?.hasError = true
                            self?.messageError = result.message!
                        } else if result.code == 200, result.status == "ok" {
                            let token = UUID().uuidString
                            UserDefaults.standard.set(token, forKey: "token")
                            UserDefaults.standard.set(result.data?.codigo, forKey: "codigo")
                            AppManager.Authenticated.send(true)
                        }

                    } catch let error {
                        self?.hasError = true
                        self?.messageError = error.localizedDescription
                    }
                
                    ´
                }
            }
        }
        
        task.resume()
            
    }

}
```

Gracias por su tiempo.

Saludos.